# php function is unable to return a value

Tags: php

I was unable to get a value from a function.
While I was going to print the value, its showing the old value "8". It seems function validateInput() is not working.

```
$current_val = "8";
function validateInput() {
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    //$search = $this->item->producer;
    $query = " SELECT * FROM aua8l_djc2_after_reg_page ";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->query();
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
               $curr = $row['type'];
               global $current_val;
                   switch ($curr) {
                    case '1':
                        $current_val = "youtube";
                        return $current_val;
                        //echo $current_val;
                        //return $GLOBALS['current_val'];
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        $current_val = "rdparty";
                        //return $GLOBALS['current_val'];
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        $current_val = "thankyou";
                        //return $GLOBALS['current_val'];
                        break;
                   } 
            }
        }
} 
echo $current_val;
```

Comment: you want to do `return $current_val;` at the end of your function and then do `$current_val = validateInput();`

Comment: At no point is the function *executed*, so yes, it won't do anything.

Comment: sorry sir, I cant get you Clearly......

Comment: Done...but still not working...
 validateInput();
 echo $current_val;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of doing it is this:

```
$current_val = "8";

function validateInput() {
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = " SELECT * FROM aua8l_djc2_after_reg_page ";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->query();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $curr = $row['type'];
            global $current_val;
            switch ($curr) {
                case '1':
                    $current_val = "youtube";
                break;
                case '2':
                    $current_val = "rdparty";
                break;
                case '3':
                    $current_val = "thankyou";
                break;
            } 
        }
        return $current_val;
    }
}
```

Now you can do either

```
echo validateInput();
```

or

```
$current_val = validateInput();
```

and `$current_val` will be what you want.

Comment: Thanks, Sir......working fine....You Make my day...

Answer (score 1):

```
$current_val = "8";
$current_val = validateInput($current_val);

function validateInput($current_val) {
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
//$search = $this->item->producer;
$query = " SELECT * FROM aua8l_djc2_after_reg_page ";
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->query();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           $curr = $row['type'];
           global $current_val;
               switch ($curr) {
                case '1':
                    $current_val = "youtube";
                    return $current_val;
                    //echo $current_val;
                    //return $GLOBALS['current_val'];
                    break;
                case '2':
                    $current_val = "rdparty";
                    //return $GLOBALS['current_val'];
                    break;
                case '3':
                    $current_val = "thankyou";
                    //return $GLOBALS['current_val'];
                    break;
               } 
        }
    }
} 
echo $current_val;
```

Comment: its displaying...Fatal error: Call to undefined function validateImput().

Comment: @user2980415 typo. Imput/Input

Comment: sorry sir...Cant get you

Comment: He's saying he made a typo which is now fixed. This should work. @user2980415

Comment: I pushed the wrong button. I was supposed to push the button `N` but I pushed `M` by mistake. That is generally called a typo. The answer has been updated without the typo.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function validateInput() in line no. 2

Comment: @user2980415 in that case the error is on your side. See here https://3v4l.org/JamLL there is a error but that is the link to database. Not to the function. Have you copied and pasted my code EXACTLY or did you make changes?